# How to enter/line-breaks in the About Me section of profile

Tags: support, profile-page

How does one add enter/line-breaks in the "About Me" section of your profile?

Comment: You can add `<br>`s.

Comment: The same way you do it in posts. Markdown supports double space before a line break.

Comment: With the <enter> key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your *About Me* is a [markdown document](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/why-is-the-about-me-field-in-a-profile-not-markdown-enabled), just like questions and answers are, so you can use [the Markdown formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in that description.

To add a line break between two adjacent lines, add *two* spaces at the end of the first line. Or use  `<br/>`, which is [on the accepted HTML tag whitelist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

Quoting from the linked help page, from the [Linebreaks section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks):

> End a line with two spaces to add a `<br/>` linebreak:
>
> ```
> How do I love thee?  
> Let me count the ways
> ```